# Reading data attribute after AJAX call

Tags: ajax, attributes

I'm having some trouble reading a data attribute value after updating through an AJAX call.

Here's the call, which works and updates the data-paged value successfully.

```
$('.block-resource-feed').on('click','#get-more-posts div',function(){

  // Get current paged value
  var paged = $(this).data('paged');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: jsVar.ajax_url,
    dataType: "html",
    data: {
      action : 'get_more_posts',
      paged : paged
    },
    success: function( response ) { 

      // Return data
      $('#post-feed').append(response);

      // Updated paged value
      $('#get-more-posts div').attr('data-paged',paged + 1);

    }
  });

})
```

and the HTML side for the button;

```
<div id="get-more-posts">

  <div data-count="13" data-paged="2">More resources</div>

</div>
```

The issue arrises when clicking the div again and the value always stays at 2, despite changing in the DOM.

I thought using the above on click method should allow reading of DOM elements after the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set/update this values on instance of your `this` element.

Add this above ajax call

```
const self = $(this);
```

and change your code in success callback

```
$('#get-more-posts div').attr('data-paged',paged + 1);
```

to

```
self.data('paged',paged+1);
```

This will work now.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/daremachine/7pbes30q/25/)